# My android sdk not opening up

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

I downloaded the package and unzipped it. When I click SDK application,black screen blinks for a fraction of second but sdk interface doesn't open.When I open it through eclipse, an error says "An outline is not available"?

There are 3 components in the package, namely Eclipse folder, SDK folder and SDK manager application.

The SDK application does not show the android icon. So I think there's some problem with the application.

Check out these snapshots :

- [snapshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58qI9.jpg)
- [snapshot2](http://imgur.com/fNj2w4i)

I have the latest version of JDK installed. It's X64 for 64bit OS.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try window-->sdk manager? if it didn't work either try copying the sdk application and paste it in the sdk folder and try again

Comment: what window ? can u please explain ?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.ht

Get Eclipse as well as SDK from this link it contain both 
After Installing JDK just open Eclipse from Eclipse folder it will automatically take SDK location.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to download Eclipse ADT version 22.6.3, you can download it from:

http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-22.6.3.zip

Also,if you can't launch the SDK there are two ways, go to SDK - tools - android.bat, it will launch the SDK :)